# Dividing streets to smaller segments in OSmnx

Tags: python, osmnx

Is it possible to divide street segments to smaller parts in OSmnx? For instance let's say we want to divide a street in 10 meter segments or divide a street into 10 equal parts.

```py
G = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, California, USA', network_type='drive')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, node_zorder=2, node_color='w', bgcolor='k')
```

[image]

Let's say in this example, I want to have 10 nodes, equally distanced, in streets whose lengths are greater than 50 meter. Is this possible? I have already looked at [OSmnx documentations](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) but I am not sure if this feature exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subdivide the road's *geometry* like that by using the [redistribute_vertices](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils_geo.redistribute_vertices) function. You would then have to manually create graph nodes at each geometry vertex. Note also that you can get a finer grained graph initially by simply passing `simplify=False` when you create the graph.

EDIT: note that the `redistribute_vertices` function has since been deprecated. Use the `interpolate_points` function instead: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils_geo.interpolate_points

Comment: A combination of `simplify=False` and `consolidate_intersections` function is what I needed! Thanks

Comment: @Rob could you explain how you figured this out in the end? I can see how you aggregate intersections, but not how you break long roads into segments!