# How do I "drop a breadcrumb" along an edge every N meters to create inbetween nodes in OSMNX?

Tags: osmnx

Is there a way in OSMNX to add inbetween nodes along each edge of a projected graph every N meters?

This is I suppose the opposite of simplification in a way.

If there's a long curve on a road, the nodes should still be added on the curve not as the crow flies.

[image: like this]

```py
import osmnx as ox

G = ox.graph_from_place('Cortlandt, New York', network_type='drive', simplify=True)

Gp = ox.project_graph(G)

nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(Gp)

# nodes is a GeoDataFrame with GeoSeries of "osmid", "y", "x", "lat", "lon", "highway", and "geometry"

# this is awkward to reference

ls = edges["geometry"][191122010][3046769062]
length_m = edges["length"][191122010][3046769062][0]

d_m = 0

while d_m < length_m:
  point = ls.interpolate(d_m)

  node = ...       # TODO

  G.add_node(node)

  d_m += 50
```

The question is thus how I do create a node that has the same attributes as other nodes on the edge but doesn't use a LineString but rather a point?  And how would I get a lat, lon from the interpolated point?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62440539/dividing-streets-to-smaller-segments-in-osmnx